# API v3's brandingSettings inconsistently returning data

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube recently released the new brandingSettings return object in to the response of /channel/list, but it seems very inconsistent in returning data.

**What are the situations where that will return data?**

**Is it only returned for YouTube Partner API accounts?** I've been testing with both, but seem to get some of it for authenticated accounts using non-Partner keys.

**Can I only get the full data set (image, channel, hints, ...) if the partner API account is a manager of the requested channel?**

**Is it limited to users using the new channel layout?**

I'm just getting a very sparse data when testing it on both channels I have authorized, authorized and managed, and public, so any information on this would be very helpful.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#properties

Answer (score 0):

The `brandingSettings` part is supported for all types of channels, and should be modifiable when you're authorized as the channel itself, or via delegation using the `onBehalfOfContentOwner=` parameter. You can retrieve it's current settings using `youtube.channels.list(part='id,brandingSettings', mine=true)`, make changes to the fields, and then pass in the modified JSON to `youtube.channels.update(part='id,brandingSettings')`

I'm fairly sure that only the latest channel layout is supported.

The one field that can't be updated is the channel title, as that needs to be changed via Google+ for linked channels (and the decision was made not to make it editable via the API for non-linked channels).